# new column not recognized in symfony2 Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine

I use symfony 2.4 and postgresql on my project. on my locale everything works fine, but on server it gives error

```
 "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException' with message 'SELECT p.id, p.username, p.email, p.isEmailConfirmed FROM CityDomGameBundle:Player p WHERE p.email = (:email) AND p.username != (:username)' in /var/...
```

error happens here

```
$duplicatedEmails = $em->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select('p.id, p.username, p.email, p.isEmailConfirmed')
                ->from('CityDomGameBundle:Player', 'p')
                ->where('p.email = (:email)')
                ->andWhere('p.username != (:username)')
                ->setParameter(':email', $email)
                ->setParameter(':username', $username)
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
```

i added new column `isEmailConfirmed` to my table, so it seems like symfony doesn't recognize it. if I remove `p.isEmailConfirmed` from `select` statement, it will work.

here's entity code

```
 /**
 * @var boolean $isEmailConfirmed
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="isemailconfirmed", type="boolean")
 */
private $isEmailConfirmed;
```

and methods

```
 /**
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getIsEmailConfirmed()
{
    return $this->isEmailConfirmed;
}

/**
 * @param $isEmailConfirmed
 * @return $this
 */
public function setIsEmailConfirmed($isEmailConfirmed)
{
    $this->isEmailConfirmed = $isEmailConfirmed;

    return $this;
}
```

i tried to `cache:clear` but it doesn't help. any idea?

**UPDATE**

after running php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force it shows errors

```
 [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\NotNullConstraintViolationException]                                      
  An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE player ADD 
  isemailconfirmed BOOLEAN NOT NULL':  
  SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  column 
  "isemailconfirmed" contains null values 

[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]                                                            
 SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  column 
 "isemailconfirmed" contains null values
```

but default value for this column is `false`
here's query when i added column

```
alter table player add column isEmailConfirmed boolean default false;
```

Comment: Have you update the schame on your server? bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force ?

Comment: is your `isemailconfirmed` in your database ?

Comment: @Alessandro Minoccheri I will try it now

Comment: @t-n-y  yes, it is

Comment: `  An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE player ADD isemailconfirmed BOOLEAN NOT NULL':  
  SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  column "isemailconfirmed" contains null values`

Comment: do you want your fiel nullable or not ? if yes put nullable to true in the entity , if not, put values in your database

Comment: question is updated

Comment: @t-n-y yes, i want to set false for default, i just run this query `update player set isEmailConfirmed = false where isEmailConfirmed IS NULL; ` , but i got `UPDATE 0`

Answer (score 0):

Update the current table first:

```
update player set isemailconfirmed = false where isemailconfirmed is null
```

Or change the annotation like this:

```
/**
 * @var boolean $isEmailConfirmed
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="isemailconfirmed", type="boolean", nullable=true)
 */
private $isEmailConfirmed;
```